# Selecting only specific features not all, and dragging and dropping correctly

Tags: javascript, openlayers, select, react

**First issue:**
I would like to select only a few features and not select rest

Let imagine I have 5 features in below code you will see that I can select all of them.

**Second issue**
The second issue is related to translating feature, it is working while selecting feature through a *click* event, however, I want to use *pointerMove* event

```
condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
```

But in that case, dragging feature is freezing

***The main parts of code are below, have you ever faced this kind problems and how did you solve?***

```
const source = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [polygonFeature, text1, text2, text3, text4],
    });
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    });

const translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
   features: select.getFeatures(),
});

const modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
   features: select.getFeatures()
});

const initMap = () => {
   map = new ol.Map({
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, translate, modify]),
      target: 'map',
      layers: layersCollections,
      view: view,
   });
};
```

Comment: I believe this example describes your problem: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/translate-features.html?q=translate

Comment: Yes it works fine, but I would like to select features based on pointermove not click, in that example I need first select then drag fetaure and for each time selection process takes a delay. Instead of that it is preferable way to select a feature when mouse over feature. When I am using pointermove, I can easly select feature when mouse over but now translating is freezing.

Comment: Basic policy of this site states: `Asking one, and only one, important question within your Question helps attract prompt and clear Answers. Your other questions are just as easy to research/ask separately!`. Please focus your question to only one question and put the other one in a new question.

Answer (score 2):

For the first issue you need to specify a filter option on the select interaction, for example to restrict the select to your polygonFeature:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    filter: function(feature){ return feature === polygonFeature; },
    });
```

Comment: Wow, thanks ) what about second issue, do you have any suggestion for dragging feature?

Comment: If you want to select using pointermove and use translate you will need a custom condition function to prevent selection while dragging because translate uses that https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/OJPLOwV

Comment: The Mike solution works for me. 
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({condition:function(event){return event.type === 'pointermove' && !event.dragging;}});